# Git push from Netbeans 8.2 on Windows 10 (ed25519)

Tags: git, push, netbeans-8, ed25519

I am not able to push changes into a remote repository from Netbeans (version 8.2) when a public/private key pair has the encryption ed25519 (and not RSA). Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: What happens when you try?  Do you get an error message, and if so, what does it say?  Also, have you tried pushing to the same repository from the command line using the same key?  What happens then?  I think this would be useful for anyone trying to help you to know.

Comment: When I try to make a git push I get the error message "Incorrect credentials for repository at [repository-url]". Netbeans also shows me an RSA fingerprint which is not identical to the fingerprint of my public key - because the fingerprint of my public key is not encrypted with RSA but with ed25519.

When I make a git push from the command line (in Windows Powershell) everything works fine. It seems as if Netbeans assumes that the encryption method for SSH keys should be RSA which is no longer available for OpenSSH on Windows 10. Only ed25519 is supported.